# Is there any way to fix this code to avoid error : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' each time

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ($firstName&&$lastName&&$email!=""){
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql= "UPDATE abonnenter SET id = (id+1)";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO abonnenter (id,firstname,lastname,mail)
    VALUES (id,'$firstName','$lastName', '$email')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Du blir nå sendt en mail når bloggen oppdateres";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
    }
}
```

is the code. It Works when I have id get -1 instead of +1, but having a primary key id be listed as negative numbers seem very bad when it comes to keeping the code semantic

Comment: `id` field must be `AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: You can use **on duplicate update key**. This will update an existing entry if the key is already there, else insert. `INSERT INTO table SET col1=?, col2=? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=?, col2=?`

Comment: Why do you change the ids of the existing rows in the `abonnenter` table? You usually don't change the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Made the id auto increment. and update your sql query like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO abonnenter (firstname,lastname,mail)
VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName', '$email')";
```

Also your code is open to sql injection use pdo or prepared statement

Comment: "_Also your code is open to sql injection_" So is yours